# Data Structure, don't want to store a list as text

Tags: sql, database-design, postgresql, data-structures

All -
   I need some help designing a table for a Postgre SQL database. I have a table of products ie;

```
CREATE TABLE products (  
    product_id integer PRIMARY KEY,  
    product_name text,  
    price numeric);  

INSERT INTO products (product_id, product_name, price) VALUES   
(DEFAULT, 'Purple Widget', '5.50'),  
(DEFAULT, 'Green Widget', '1.50'),  
(DEFAULT, 'Yellow Widget', '5.50'),  
(DEFAULT, 'Spotted Widget', '6.50'),  
(DEFAULT, 'Extra Large Purple Widget', '102.50'),  
(DEFAULT, 'Extra Large Spotted Widget', '101.50');
```

I want to start selling a package of products (multiple products, one price). I am trying to figure out a structure for a packages table. Two options I don't like are -

```
CREATE TABLE packages (  
    package_id integer PRIMARY KEY,   
    package_name text,
    package_products varchar(50),  
    price numeric);  

INSERT INTO packages (package_id, package_name, package_products, price) VALUES  
    (DEFAULT, 'Small Widgets', '0,1,2,3', '6.25'),  
    (DEFAULT, 'Large Widgets', '5,6', '200.00');
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE packages (  
    package_id integer PRIMARY KEY,   
    package_name text,
    product_id1 integer,  
    product_id2 integer,  
    product_id3 integer,  
    product_id4 integer,  
    product_id5 integer,  
    price numeric);  

INSERT INTO packages (package_id, package_name, product_id1, product_id2, 
                      product_id3, product_id4, product_id5, price) VALUES  
    (DEFAULT, 'Small Widgets', '0', '1' ,'2', '3', NULL, '6.25'),  
    (DEFAULT, 'Large Widgets', '5', '6', NULL, NULL, NULL, '200.00');
```

I can't move the packages logic to the products table because each product could be in multiple packages. Both of those options above require a lot of work at the web layer to make work, plus they both seem really inefficient.

Ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a standard [many-to-many](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php) relationship (many packages to many items)

```
CREATE TABLE products (
product_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
product_name text,
price numeric);

CREATE TABLE packages (
package_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
package_name text,
price numeric); 

CREATE TABLE package_items (
package_item_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
package_id integer,
product_id integer,
qty integer );
```

Comment: I'd put the PK on package_id and product_id or at the VERY LEAST, put a unique index on them.

Comment: Could go either way, depending on if you plan to use packages in another table for some reason or not.  But you're right, they do need at least a unique index

Answer (score 4):

Also note that you should put foreign key constraints on columns that reference rows in other tables.

```
CREATE TABLE PackageProduct (
product_id integer,
package_id integer,
FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES Product(product_id),
FOREIGN KEY (package_id) REFERENCES Package(package_id));
```

Comment: I do in production, I just threw this together as an example, but thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

What about a Package table and a PackageProduct table?

```
CREATE TABLE Product (
product_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
product_name text,
price numeric); 

CREATE TABLE Package (
package_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
package_name text
price numeric); 

CREATE TABLE PackageProduct (
product_id integer,
package_id integer);
```

Then just add your packages to the package table and add a row for each product in a package to the PackageProduct table.